# Pass multiple parameters to return personalized page in MVC in DocuSign <returnUrl> XML tag

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign REST API to integrate agreement signing within a C# MVC application.  I've gotten almost all the functionality to work the way I'd like, however I'm having some trouble with the page that is loaded after signing is complete in the DocuSign iframe.  I created a view in my project outside of my template authentication and have pointed the XML "returnUrl" tag to it.

It now loads that page, however the problem comes from trying to pass in multiple parameters.  Ideally I'd like to pass in 3 different strings but the XML request errors when I try to have all 3 query string parameter in the URL.  With one it goes through just fine.

Current code that doesn't error out and allows signing process to finish while passing a single parameter to the after signing page:

```
string reqBody = "<recipientViewRequest xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                "<authenticationMethod>email</authenticationMethod>" +
                    "<email>" + model.TSM.Email + "</email>" +      // NOTE: Use different email address if username provided in non-email format!
                    "<returnUrl>https://maaxspasportal.com/TerritorySalesManagement/AfterSigningLandingPage?contactName=" + model.ContactName.Replace(" ", "%20") + "</returnUrl>" +  // username can be in email format or an actual ID string
                    "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" +
                    "<userName>" + model.TSM.Name + "</userName>" +
                    "</recipientViewRequest>";
```

Code that makes the XML request invalid returning an error:

```
            string contactName = model.ContactName.Replace(" ", "%20");
            string companyName = model.CompanyName.Replace(" ", "%20");
            string contactEmail = model.Dealer.Email.Replace(" ", "%20");

            string reqBody = "<recipientViewRequest xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                "<authenticationMethod>email</authenticationMethod>" +
                    "<email>" + model.TSM.Email + "</email>" +      // NOTE: Use different email address if username provided in non-email format!
                    "<returnUrl>https://maaxspasportal.com/TerritorySalesManagement/AfterSigningLandingPage?contactName=" + contactName + "&companyName=" + companyName + "&contactEmail=" + contactEmail + "</returnUrl>" +  // username can be in email format or an actual ID string
                    "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" +
                    "<userName>" + model.TSM.Name + "</userName>" +
                    "</recipientViewRequest>";
```

And here is the error that I receive:

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><errorCode>INVALID_REQUEST_BODY</errorCode><message>The request body is missing or improperly formatted. An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 271.</message></errorDetails>
```

Has anyone run into this before?  Is there a better way for me to pass parameters to my "returnUrl" page?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: It might be the characters returned from the individual objects returned may have invalid characters, without seeing the end result of what is returned I can't say for sure, but have you tried prepending the reqBody with @?

Comment: I'd also say, you should use the StringBuilder class, it's much more efficient ;)

Comment: By individual objects I assume you mean the 3 strings I'm trying to pass as URL query parameters?  If so I don't think any bad characters are being assigned to them.  I've been able to pass companyName and contactName individually but when I try to pass both I get this same error.  Same with prepending reqBody with @.  Good advice on the StringBuilder, I should probably use it more often.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try encoding the ampersand (**&**) in the URL.  For example, try setting **returnUrl** to something like this:

```
<returnUrl>https://maaxspasportal.com/TerritorySalesManagement/AfterSigningLandingPage?contactName=John%20Smith&#038;companyName=ABC_Company&#038;contactEmail=johnsmith@test.com</returnUrl>
```

Notice I've replaced each occurrence of **&** with **&#038 ;**  (with no space between the **8** and the **;**)

**UPDATE:**  Here's the full XML request to get the Recipient URL:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient

<recipientViewRequest xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <authenticationMethod>Email</authenticationMethod>
  <email>johnsmith@test.com</email>  
  <returnUrl>https://maaxspasportal.com/TerritorySalesManagement/AfterSigningLandingPage?contactName=John%20Smith&#038;companyName=ABC_Company&#038;contactEmail=johnsmith@test.com</returnUrl>
  <clientUserId>123</clientUserId>
  <userName>John Smith</userName>
</recipientViewRequest>
```

The response returned is as follows:

```
<viewUrl 
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <url>https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?t=87aaeca6-77cd-44f5-9ec0-8384270f52e7</url>
</viewUrl>
```

In a new browser, I navigate to the URL specified in the **url** element of the response and complete/confirm signing.  Upon submitting the envelope, I am redirected to the redirect page that I had previously specified in the request.  The page appears to be successfully parsing all 3 querystring parameters:

[image]

Comment: Well it's definitely the "&" symbol that's mucking things up, however when I encode it then it sets the first parameter (contactName) as the whole string after it rather than breaking it out to all three parameters. So you end up with contactName being equal to "John Smith&companyName=ABC_Company&contactEmail=johnsmith@test.com".  You can run that URL and see what shows up.  There should be a line for each variable (contact, company and email).  Contact, Company and Email are the defaults.

Comment: I've updated my answer -- try this approach instead: replace the & with &#38; instead.

Comment: It looks like the request doesn't like the & symbol being present at all.  Also from what I read the # symbol ends the query string prematurely.  Even if the XML would return correctly with the & symbol you can run your newest returnUrl example and see that only John Smith is passed in and reflected on the page.  Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Using &#38; in the returnUrl works for me. I'll update my answer to include the full XML request.  Give it a shot and you should see (like I did) that when the signer is redirected to your page upon submitting the envelope, the page is able to successfully parse all 3 querystring parameters.

Comment: Hmm you're right.  Not sure why my first test failed, I must have put something in wrong.  I'm seeing that &amp; also works.  Thank you very much!  Now the real question is why I decided in my original code that I needed to encode the spaces but not the ampersand hah.